# Python, Tkinter: How to get a widget to run function on pack?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Say I have an instance of a custom class, `CustomFrame`, which inherits from Tkinter's Frame widget asssigned to `custom_frame`, a child of a `root` parent Tk window widget, and I pack (or place or grid) it:

```
custom_frame = CustomFrame(root)
custom_frame.pack()
```

Is there a way to make the `custom_frame` run a method of `CustomFrame` when it is packed, *without* just calling the function before packing `custom_frame`? For example, somehow overriding the usual `pack` method to run the usual `pack` method and then call another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are defining the frame anyway, just add this to your frame:

```
def pack(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomFrame, self).pack(*args, **kwargs)
    # Do whatever
```

Comment: If that works that's great, I didn't realise you could just shadow the pack method like that. Thanks!